# WPF and AutoRedraw

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a custom WPF Line and its style. UserControl Resources:

```
    <!-- Framework properties to update -->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyLineBrush" Color="LightGreen" />
    <sys:Double x:Key="MyLineStrokeThickness">1</sys:Double>

    <!-- Custom property to update -->
    <sys:Boolean x:Key="MyLineIsArrowUsed">false</sys:Boolean>


    <Style TargetType="local:MyLine" x:Key="MyLineStyleKey">

        <!-- AutoUpdates the control -->
        <Setter Property="Fill" 
                Value="{DynamicResource MyLineBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" 
                Value="{DynamicResource MyLineStrokeThickness}" />

        <!-- does NOT AutoUpdate the control -->
        <Setter Property="ShowText" 
                Value="{DynamicResource MyLineIsArrowUsed}"/>
```

Now, I observed when I update the `MyLineStrokeThickness` the control is updated instantly. 
but when I update my custom dependency property `MyLineIsArrowUsed` there are no changes.

**What should I use in order to update the custom control (line) drawing once my custom dependency property is updated?**

I tried:

```
static void OnIsArrowUsedChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var s = (MyLine)source;
    s.UpdateLayout();            
}
```

but this does not work.

The control updates only when I move it or do other actions when it is forced to redraw itself.

Comment: Can you post the DP code behind...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the dependency property declaration add FrameworkPropertyMetadata.AffectsMeasure

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadata.affectsmeasure.aspx

Comment: it was AffectsRender. Thank you much!

Comment: Actually I first typed in AffectsRender but then saw you were drawing an arrow at the end (exactly what I did myself) so assumed you must also be calculating stuff and so suggested AffectsMeasure. Glad it helped though.

Comment: the arrow is drawn in the middle. Logically thinking, it affects the Measure too, but AffectsMeasure didn't help, so I tried other flags :)

Comment: Ok. I derived from Shape and overrode DefiningGeometry which does some custom calculations. I guess you must be overriding OnRender to add your arrow.